# ViewModels inside a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller, web-deployment

I'm fairly new to MVC and C# and I find myself stuck with this problem.

I have 3 tables: *UserCredentials*, *BusinessCredentials* and *BusinessDetails*.
I created 3 ViewModels:

**UserBusinessListingViewModel**

```
[Display(Name = "User Id:")]
public int User_Id { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<BusinessCredentialsViewModel> BusinessCredentialsViewModels {get; set;}
```

**BusinessCredentialsViewModel**

```
[Display(Name = "Business Id:")]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Name:")]
public string Name { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<BusinessDetailsViewModel> BusinessDetailsViewModels { get; set; }
```

**BusinessDetailsViewModel**.

```
[Display(Name = "Id:")]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Category:")]
public string Category { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Rating:")]
public float Rating { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Country:")]
public string Country { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "State:")]
public string State { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "City:")]
public string City { get; set; }
```

The main view model is **UserBusinessListingViewModel**; it has to display information from all the 3 tables above.

In the Controller I have

```
UserCredential businessSectionUserCredential = 
    _unitOfWork.UserCredentials
            .Include("BusinessCredentials")
            .Include("BusinessCredentials.BusinessDetails")
            .First(p => p.Id == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);

var userBusinessListingViewModel = new UserBusinessListingViewModel();
userBusinessListingViewModel.User_Id = businessSectionUserCredential.Id;
```

and I'm stuck here.

```
userBusinessListingViewModel.BusinessCredentialsViewModels
```

has no properties. How do I map this?

Thank you.

I want to achieve something like this.
Done this before, but this is easy because I only have one view-model:

```
var profileViewModel = new ProfileViewModel();

UserCredential userCredential = _unitOfWork.UserCredentials.Include(p => p.UserDetail).First(p => p.Id == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
UserDetail userDetail = userCredential.UserDetail;

profileViewModel.UserCredentials_Id = userCredential.Id;
profileViewModel.Email = userCredential.Email;
profileViewModel.FirstName = userDetail.FirstName;
profileViewModel.LastName = userDetail.LastName;
return PartialView("_ProfilePartial", profileViewModel);
```

I am using

```
@model BusinessListing.ViewModels.UserBusinessListingViewModel
<div class="col-md-8">
    <p class="p-custom-bg">@Model.User_Id</p>
</div>
```

to display this.

Comment: `userBusinessListingViewModel.BusinessCredentialsViewModels` has no properties because it is an IEnumerable<>. You can access each of the items using `.Select(b=> b.Name)

Comment: Something like `userBusinessListingViewModel.BusinessCredentialsViewModels = businessSectionUserCredential.BusinessCredentials.Select(x => new BusinessCredentialsViewModel() { ID = x.ID, NAme = x.Name, etc });`

Answer (score 2):

You don't have `Add` or any methods like that on `BusinessCredentialsViewModels` because it is an `IEnumerable`. You have, however, defined a getter and a setter for it so you can do something like this:

```
userBusinessListingViewModel.BusinessCredentialsViewModels = array;
```

without knowing more of your code I can't helpfully tell you the exact code to write. But say that `UserCredential` has a property `BusinessCredientials` which is an `IEnumerable<BusinessCredential>`, you could then do:

```
userBusinessListingViewModel.BusinessCredentialsViewModels
    = userCredential.BusinessCredentials.Select(
        x => new BusinessCredentialsViewModel
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                /* etc, etc */
            });
```

Comment: I want to do something like this:

    'var profileViewModel = new ProfileViewModel();
     UserCredential userCredential = _unitOfWork.UserCredentials.Include(p => p.UserDetail).First(p => p.Id == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
     UserDetail userDetail = userCredential.UserDetail;

     profileViewModel.UserCredentials_Id = userCredential.Id;
     profileViewModel.Email = userCredential.Email;
     profileViewModel.FirstName = userDetail.FirstName;
     return PartialView("_ProfilePartial", profileViewModel);'
This was easy because I have only one view model.

Comment: @DanielStoica If you have more information to post, please do so in the question itself.

Comment: The view is not populated. Updated with what code I use in the View

Answer (score 0):

userBusinessListingViewModel.BusinessCredentialsViewModels is a IEnumerable and thus you do not see the properties.

Create an object of BusinessCredentialsViewModel and then assign values to its properties. Once all properties of the object have been assigned values, add it to userBusinessListingViewModel.BusinessCredentialsViewModels. For Example :

```
var businessCredentialsViewModel = new BusinessCredentialsViewModel();    
businessCredentialsViewModel.Name = "SomeName";    userBusinessListingViewModel.BusinessCredentialsViewModels.Add(businessCredentialsViewModel);
```